# Symfony Configuration Parsing

Tags: symfony

I have the following configuration on my config.yml

```
ci_api:
    file:
        purposes:
            attachment:
```

And my configuration class looks like this:

```
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('ci_api');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('file')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('purposes')
                        ->children()

                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end(); //children

    return $treeBuilder;
```

When i tried to run this it gets an error saying:

> Unrecognized option "attachment" under "ci_api.file.purposes"

Note that under purposes there can be indefinite number of children.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding  `->prototype('array')`  before last `children()`

Comment: yeah, it did worked .Thanks.

Comment: I post the comment as an answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the prototype definition as array on the last element definition as follow:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('file')
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('purposes')
                    ->prototype('array')  // Add this line
                    ->children()

                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end(); //children
```